# Unable to access property values of a class from another class in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to access property values of a class from another class but unable to do so. I may be doing it wrong and hence I'm here looking for answers.

In my app there is a class called CartRepository which holds cart items.

```
class CartRepository {
  List<Product> cartItems = [];

  List<Product> get getCartItems => cartItems;
  
  void addItem(Product product) {
    cartItems.add(product);
  }
}
```

Through bloc I'm updating the values of cartItems by creating an object for CartRepository.

There is another class called OrderRepository where I need to bring in the cartItems from CartRepository along with other information from UI and update it in a db.

But when I create another object for CartRepository inside OrderBloc and access the cartItems, the value it returns is an empty List. How can I access the cartItems that has the data in another place?

OrderBloc

```
class OrderProviderBloc extends Bloc<OrderProviderEvent, OrderProviderState> {
  OrderProviderBloc() : super(OrderProviderInitial());

  CartRepository cartRepository = CartRepository();
  OrderRepository orderRepository = OrderRepository();


  @override
  Stream<OrderProviderState> mapEventToState(
    OrderProviderEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is PlaceOrderEvent) {
      try {
        orderRepository.placeOrder(cartRepository.cartItems,event.userMobileNumber);
      } on Exception {}
    }
  }
}
```

OrderRepository

```
class OrderRepository extends Equatable {
  final List<Order> orders = [];

  void placeOrder(
      List<Product> cartItems, String userMobileNumber) {
    orders.add(Order(
        userMobileNumber: userMobileNumber,
        productsFromCart: cartItems));
    addOrderToFirebase(cartItems, userMobileNumber);
  }
```

Comment: `CartRepository().cartItems` always creates a new `CartRepository` object that starts off with an empty `cartItems` list. "I used Equatable so that wherever I create an object, it points to the same place in memory." That's not what `package:equatable` does. (Unrelated, but making `_cartItems` private with a public getter is pointless since `_cartItems` is final.  Just make it public in the first place.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As you can see I'm a newbie to Flutter and Dart. CartRepository().cartItems is used for debugging and has nothing to do with code functionality. Also I made cartItems as public and took away the final keyword. Yet doing all these doesn't really work. I still have the same problem. The cartItems inside OrderBloc still returns an empty result.

Comment: You're asking why `cartItems` is an empty list, but you haven't shown any code where you actually add any items to it.  It's not even clear where you observe `cartItems` being unexpectedly empty.  It's *much* easier to help if you provide a minimal, reproducible example demonstrating the problem that you're encountering. (The process of creating the minimal example often can help you find the cause on your own.)

Answer (score -1):

###### DO NOT set variables using getters!

###### DO NOT set value to final variables after declaring them

In these lines

```
        List<Product> cartItems = CartRepository().cartItems;
        print("Total from cart repository -------- ${cartRepository.totalCValue}");
        orderRepository.placeOrder(cartRepository.cartItems,
            cartRepository.totalCValue, event.userMobileNumber);
```

You are using getters to set values,
to fix this, add a setter along with the existing getter in `CartRepository`

Also since it's a final variable you need to call `clear` and then call`addAll` to add new items to it.

```
class CartRepository extends Equatable {
  final List<Product> _cartItems = [];

  List<Product> get cartItems => _cartItems;
  set cartItems(List<Product> newCardItems){
    _cartItems.clear();
    _cartItems.addAll(newCardItems);
  }
}
```

What this line will do? you are not using this variable.

```
List<Product> cartItems = CartRepository().cartItems;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question again. Please consider looking at it again.